# How to get notified in parent process when a child is sent SIGCONT?

Tags: c, wait, daemon, child-process

I'm working on a taskmaster, very much like supervisor: it runs multiple programs from a configuration file then I can stop / restart / log information about those programs.

I `fork()` then `execve()` (discarding the program's output). In parent process I listen to SIGCHLD signal.

The problem is that on OSX, SIGCHLD isn't sent on SIGCONT, while on Ubuntu it does.

So, is there a portable way to get notified in main process that a child has been sent SIGCONT? It would be perfect to receive a signal when a child has SIGCONTinued.

I could run a separate thread and `waitpid()` with WUNTRACED every second, but I need precise information (I need to log the process' running time for example).

I could workaround some stuff in my taskmaster to make it somehow work, but if the process is sent SIGCONT outside of my program, I won't be normally notified about that.

Quotes from manual:

> The SIGCHLD signal is sent to a process when a child process
>   terminates, is interrupted, or resumes after being interrupted.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a problem on macOS. I started a new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487935/sigchld-is-sent-on-sigcont-on-linux-but-not-on-macos