# SIGCHLD is sent on SIGCONT on Linux but not on macOS

Tags: c, linux, macos, signals, child-process

In the main process I listen to SIGCHLD:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, &my_handler);
```

Then I `fork()`, `execv()` and let it run in background (/bin/cat for example).

When I try from terminal to send SIGSTOP to the child process, `my_handler()` gets called. But when I try to send SIGCONT to it, the the handler isn't called on macOS but it's executed on my Ubuntu.

Man:

> SIGCHLD: child status has changed.

Am I missing something? Is it an expected behaviour? I wrote my app on Ubuntu and expected it to work on mac as well.

I tried with `sigaction()` as well, but with the same results.

Here's a sample code to demonstrate:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void    my_handler(int signum)
{
    printf("\t SIGCHLD received\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void    my_kill(pid_t pid, int signum)
{
    printf("Sending %d\n", signum);
    fflush(stdout);

    kill(pid, signum);

    printf("Sent %d\n\n", signum);
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main()
{
    pid_t   pid;
    char    *cat_args[2] = {"/bin/cat", NULL};

    signal(SIGCHLD, &my_handler);
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        execv("/bin/cat", cat_args);
    }
    else
    {   
        my_kill(pid, SIGSTOP);
        my_kill(pid, SIGCONT);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With the output on macOS:

```
Sending 17
         SIGCHLD received
Sent 17

Sending 19
Sent 19
```

Comment: `printf("\t SIGCHLD received\n");
    fflush(stdout);`  In a signal handler?!?!?  Are you trying to deadlock your process?  You can safely call *only* async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler.  `printf()` and `fflush()` are *not* async-signal-safe.

Answer (score 5):

That behavior is optional.  An implementation need not generate a SIGCHLD upon continuation.  The language used in POSIX.1-2008 (2016 edition) is "may" rather than "shall":

> When a stopped process is continued, a SIGCHLD signal *may* be generated for its parent process, unless the parent process has set the SA_NOCLDSTOP flag.

- [System Interfaces, 2.4.3 Signal Actions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03)

> ...a SIGCHLD signal *may* be generated for the calling process whenever any of its stopped child processes are continued.

-
 [System Interfaces `sigaction` "Description"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html#tag_16_540_03)

Emphases added.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I missing something?

Probably not.

> Is it an expected behaviour?

Probably yes.

OSX is based on 4.4 BSD, and this BSD simply does not support sending a `SIGCHLD` to the parent when the child continues. Earlier versions of Linux lacked this support as well.